# Como obtengo el id del texbox cuando esta el focus

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una validación a muchos campos de texto, estos son dinamicos. Mi pregunta es como puedo saber el nombre de mi caja de texto con el metodo focus, algo asi como esto.

```
Document.getElementById("focus...")
```

¿Será que es posible?

Comment: Es completamente posible, ahí te deje una respuesta, sin embargo, te recomiendo que uses los tags de manera más precisa, porque estás preguntando por JavaScript y tu pregunta tiene como tag asp.net; si utilizas los tags de manera más precisa, es más posible que la gente indicada vea tu pregunta! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando `js` puro, puedes utilizar esto en la función donde trabajas:

```
var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
console.log(focusedElement.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, se hace de la siguiente manera;

```
// Obtenes el elemento que está en foco:
var $focused = $(':focus');

// Lo mismo pero sin jQuery:
var focused = document.activeElement;

// Retorna un booleano, true, si el elemento está en foco, y false en caso contrario:
var hasFocus = $('foo').is(':focus');

// Lo mismo pero sin jQuery:
elem === elem.ownerDocument.activeElement;
```

Aclaro; me base en la respuesta de **gdoron** en [StackOverflow e inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277989/how-to-get-the-focused-element-with-jquery)

Después, en tu caso particular, para obtener el nombre, podrías hacer algo así

```
$(':focus').attr('name')
```

Saludos!

Comment: El usuario no está usando jquery y considero que la respuesta no da una solución usando javascript nativo.